# Change nodes of treeview

Tags: c#, winforms, treeview

i have a treeview like this below
i use c# for winform programming

1. MONITOR

   - LG
   - Samsung
   - HP
2. KEYBOARD

   - HP
   - Dell

     - Black
     - White
3. MOUSE

so can u tell me how can i programmically change places of 1st and 2nd nodes in this example.

Comment: What is the code structure you use for this? or where is the output used (wpf, asp.net (mvc), winforms)?

Comment: how do you insert your data in the treeview ? what is the use case of this reorganisation ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int indCurr = treeView.SelectedNode.Index;
int levelCurr = treeView.SelectedNode.Level;
if (indCurr == 0) return;

if (levelCurr == 0)
{
  TreeNode prevNode = treeView.Nodes[indCurr - 1];
  prevNode.Remove();
  treeView.Nodes.Insert(indCurr, prevNode);
}
else
{
  TreeNode prevNode = treeView.SelectedNode.Parent.Nodes[indCurr - 1];
  prevNode.Remove();
  treeView.SelectedNode.Parent.Nodes.Insert(indCurr, prevNode);
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Simply get the reference of node you want to move, remove it and then insert it on required index

```
//get the ref
TreeNode node = treeView.Nodes[0];
//remove
treeView.Nodes[0].Remove();
//insert
treeView.Nodes.Insert(1, node);
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a compilable example. I implemented the node exchanger as an extension method of TreeView. Note the `BeginUpdate ... EndUpdate` calls. Required references: System.Core.dll, System.Drawing.dll and System.Windows.Forms.dll.

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Windows.Forms;

public static class ExtensionMethods
{
  public static void ExchangeRootNodes(this TreeView treeView, string key1, string key2)
  {
    treeView.BeginUpdate();
    try {
      int i1 = treeView.Nodes.IndexOfKey(key1);
      if (i1 == -1)
        throw new ArgumentException("No node with this key: " + key1, "key1");
      int i2 = treeView.Nodes.IndexOfKey(key2);
      if (i2 == -1)
        throw new ArgumentException("No node with this key: " + key2, "key2");
      if (i1 == i2)
        return;
      var node1 = treeView.Nodes[i1];
      var node2 = treeView.Nodes[i2];
      node1.Remove();
      node2.Remove();
      if (i1 < i2) {
        treeView.Nodes.Insert(i1, node2);
        treeView.Nodes.Insert(i2, node1);
      } else {
        treeView.Nodes.Insert(i2, node1);
        treeView.Nodes.Insert(i1, node2);
      }
    } finally {
      treeView.EndUpdate();
    }
  }
} 

public static class Program 
{
  public static void Main() 
  {
    var form = new Form() { Left = 100, Top = 100, ClientSize = new Size(220, 300), Text = "Node Exchange Test" };

    var treeView = new TreeView() { Left = 10, Top = 10, Width = 200, Height = 245 };
    form.Controls.Add(treeView);
    treeView.BeginUpdate();
    try {
      treeView.Nodes.Add("MONITOR", "MONITOR");
      treeView.Nodes[0].Nodes.Add("LG");
      treeView.Nodes[0].Nodes.Add("Samsung");
      treeView.Nodes[0].Nodes.Add("HP");
      treeView.Nodes.Add("KEYBOARD", "KEYBOARD");
      treeView.Nodes[1].Nodes.Add("HP");
      treeView.Nodes[1].Nodes.Add("Dell");
      treeView.Nodes[1].Nodes[1].Nodes.Add("Black");
      treeView.Nodes[1].Nodes[1].Nodes.Add("White");
      treeView.Nodes.Add("MOUSE", "MOUSE");
      treeView.ExpandAll();
    } finally {
      treeView.EndUpdate();
    }

    var button = new Button() {Left = 10, Top = 265, Width = 200, Height = 25, Text = "MONITOR <-> KEYBOARD" };
    form.Controls.Add(button);
    button.Click += delegate(object sender, EventArgs e) {
      try {
        treeView.ExchangeRootNodes("MONITOR", "KEYBOARD");
      } catch (ArgumentException exception) {
        MessageBox.Show(exception.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
      }
    };

    form.Visible = true;
    Application.Run(form);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are in Windows Forms.

look at this answer: [C# - TreeView: inserting node at certain position](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4329207/c-sharp-treeview-inserting-node-at-certain-position) you should insert the nodes in the position you want them to be.

in your case you could insert the node `KEYBOARD` in position 0 and the `MONITOR` node will probably move down to position 1, but you could do this when building the tree the first time directly.

Comment: hi @Davide Piras can we add another field to the products table named PositionId and can list product and its sublist according to the PositionId is that aBetter Idea?

Answer (score 0):

The clean way is to sort the tree with your custom [TreeViewNodeSorter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.treeview.sort%28v=vs.80%29.aspx). For example you can write a sort order in the Tag property of each tree node and use it for sorting the tree.